# What are the latest patches that I need to download for my MOSS 2007 server

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I just have RTM version of MOSS installed. I  wanted to download the latest service packs to make it work properly. But I am not sure what to download.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is it enough if I just install MOSS SP2 alone.

Comment: Do I have to download WSS SP2 along with MOSS SP2?
Do I have to download SP1 before downloading SP2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to install WSS service pack then MOSS service pack. If you chose to install the Moss service pack directly, it would ask for you to install WSS service pack.

[Here](http://grumpywookie.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/moss-version-checking/) is a link to check what version you have